# Creating a PHP submission handler?

Tags: php, html, css, event-handling, blogs

Can someone help me form a Submission handler for these pages? I need it to create a new php or html file that has the date and title to blogpost as the html or php link. *Example*: 12162018BlogPost.html *<-- To prevent erasing previous files on creation.*

> Each section needed edited is marked with "<!--Editing-->"

Links have been provided for ease of access.

> [Submission Form](https://timescapeinc.com/Submission_Form_2B4235x21651a15978y3B1058175Bkhw18501W1x_Post.html): HTML Below

```html
<!--Editing-->
<form id="submission" method="post" action="submission-handler.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 Blog Title:<center><textarea name="header" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Blog Post Header" rows="2" required></textarea></center>
 <br>
 Blog Content:<center><textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your blog post here" rows="10" required></textarea></center>
 <br>
 Upload an image: (Not Currently Working)
 <center><input type="file" name="filetoupload" id="filetoupload">
 <select>
 <option selected="selected" value="noimage">No Image</option>
 <option value="wrapleft">Image on Left</option>
 <option value="wrapright">Image on Right</option>
 <option value="nowrap">Image Centered</option>
 </select></center>
 <br>
 <br>
 <hr>
 <br>
 <br>
 <input type="submit" class="form-control submit" value="Preview Post" disabled>
 <input type="submit" class="form-control submit" value="Finalize Post" disabled>
</form>
<!--/Editing-->
```

> [Template Post](https://timescapeinc.com/profile/template/posts/template_post.html): HTML Editing Title, Header, Photo, and Message marked with $header, and $message

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--Blog Post Name as Title-->
<!--Editing-->
<title><?php echo = '$header'; ?> | Insert Name | TimeScape Inc</title>
<!--/Editing-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/CSS/main.css">
<link href="Resources/CSS/Extra.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../../../favicon.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-100075704-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-100075704-1');
</script>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-8019229992747723",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
</script>
<!-- Hotjar Tracking Code for www.timescapeinc.com -->
<script>
    (function(h,o,t,j,a,r){
        h.hj=h.hj||function(){(h.hj.q=h.hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
        h._hjSettings={hjid:990575,hjsv:6};
        a=o.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        r=o.createElement('script');r.async=1;
        r.src=t+h._hjSettings.hjid+j+h._hjSettings.hjsv;
        a.appendChild(r);
    })(window,document,'https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-','.js?sv=');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Background-->
<div id="back"></div>
<div id="front"></div>
<div id="front2"></div>
<!--Navigation bar-->
<div id="nav-placeholder">

</div>

<script>
$(function(){
  $("#nav-placeholder").load("../../../nav.html");
});
</script>
<!--end of Navigation bar-->
<!--Body-->
<div id="wrapper">
 <ul class="social"><li><div id="propicture"><div class="profile"><img src="Resources/IMG/7d1a3f77eee9f34782c6f88e97a6c888.jpg"></div></div></li><li><div class="information">
<!--Edit Information below-->
  <p><h2>&#60;Insert Name&#62;</h2></p>
 <p><nav><ul class="social">
 <!--Social Media 1-->
  <li><a href="https://facebook.com/editthis"><img height="50" src="Resources/IMG/cfacebook.png" alt="facebook"></a></li>
 <!--Social Media 2-->
  <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/editthis"><img height="50" src="Resources/IMG/cG+.png" alt="google+"></a></li>
 <!--Social Media 3-->
 <li><a href="https://youtube.com/editthis"><img height="50" src="Resources/IMG/cYT.png" alt="youtube"></a></li>
 <!--Social Media 4-->
  <li><a href="https://twitter.com/editthis"><img height="50" src="Resources/IMG/ctwitter.png" alt="twitter"></a></li></ul>
 </nav></p></div>
 </li></ul>
<!--About Section-->
<div class="container">
<!--Editing-->
<!--Generate Lorem Ipsum by typing lorem(number) then press tab-->
 <center><h1><?php echo = '$header'; ?></h1></center>
 <!--idk how to change below to image location and location value
 Example of location value: "nowrap", "wrapleft", "wrapright", "noimage"
 image location is "Resources/IMG/<Uploaded image>" -->
 <?php <img class="nowrap" src="Resources/IMG/755118806-cloudscape-moving-clouds-horizon-over-land-rural-scene.jpg">; ?>
  <p><?php echo = '$message'; ?></p>
  <!--/Editing-->
</div>
<!--Blog Content-->
<div class="selection">
     <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>

/**
*  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
*  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables*/
/*
var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = PAGE_URL;  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
};
*/
(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://timescapeinc.disqus.com/embed.js';
s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript><br/><br/></div></div>

<!--Footer-->
<div class="outer" align="center">
 <div class="footer">
   <p>TimeScape Inc</p>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.freevisitorcounters.com/en/home/counter/376592/t/5"></script>
   <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
          google_ad_client: "ca-pub-8019229992747723",
          enable_page_level_ads: true
     });
</script>
 </div>
</div>
<!--Share Buttons-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5b67cad9677767c0"></script>
<script id="dsq-count-scr" src="//timescapeinc.disqus.com/count.js" async></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any more details needed feel free to ask. I am willing to answer any questions.

> Current Submission Handler *I don't know what I'm doing*

```html
<?php
 $newcontent = file_get_contents("template.html");


//For Image upload
 $allow = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");

 $todir = 'Resources/IMG/';

if ( !!$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) // is the file uploaded yet?
{
    $info = explode('.', strtolower( $_FILES['file']['name']) ); // whats the extension of the file

    if ( in_array( end($info), $allow) ) // is this file allowed
    {
        if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $todir . basename($_FILES['file']['name'] ) ) )
        {
            // the file has been moved correctly
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // error this file ext is not allowed
    }
}

?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you reduce the code to that what is relevant to your problem, and please also tell us what you have trouble with. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am very bad with PHP for whatever reason learning it is a HUGE pain for me and I'm just trying to get $header and $message displayed where it says on the template above and allow the uploading of photos with content liners that are predefined through css to be plugged into the template above.